# Jenkins pipeline dir() directive causing docker container to exit

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Following on from the issue I had in this question: [Why when using Jenkins dockerfile agent does it run container with invalid user?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55146361/2547709)

I successfully managed to run the container as root user, however the actual java stack trace failure I received remained the same- implying it is not a permissions error with the user in the container.

The actual issue appears to be with the `dir() {}` step within my stage. To re-iterate, when I have the following:

```
steps {
    dir('/src') {
        sh 'pwd'  // any command
    }
}
```

the container exits without running the command:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins seems to be running inside container aaee62f2a28e29b94c13fcdc08c1a82ef7baed48beabe54579db07b2fbd26b23
$ docker run -t -d -u 1000:1000 -w "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/My Project" --volumes-from aaee62f2a28e29b94c13fcdc08c1a82ef7baed48beabe54579db07b2fbd26b23 -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** -e ******** 12724611f0bf2363c9eee7288654e43eca2aabaf cat
$ docker top 4e29bc102d8f4e6b4ffc142fc06eb706e95b00fa6190b2927f4f79f0cfa53af5 -eo pid,comm
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /src
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
$ docker stop --time=1 4e29bc102d8f4e6b4ffc142fc06eb706e95b00fa6190b2927f4f79f0cfa53af5
$ docker rm -f 4e29bc102d8f4e6b4ffc142fc06eb706e95b00fa6190b2927f4f79f0cfa53af5
```

and the failure stack trace at the end of the build is:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /src
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:384)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:674)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:781)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:767)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:3273)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1300(FilePath.java:213)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1254)
    at hudson.FilePath$Mkdirs.invoke(FilePath.java:1250)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1078)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1061)
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1246)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask$FileMonitoringController.<init>(FileMonitoringTask.java:181)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript$ShellController.<init>(BourneShellScript.java:221)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript$ShellController.<init>(BourneShellScript.java:210)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.BourneShellScript.launchWithCookie(BourneShellScript.java:131)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.durabletask.FileMonitoringTask.launch(FileMonitoringTask.java:99)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.durable_task.DurableTaskStep$Execution.start(DurableTaskStep.java:305)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:268)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:176)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:155)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:159)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:129)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:23)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor143.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:182)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

However if I use the following:

```
steps {
    sh 'cd /src && pwd'
}
```

The command runs as expected. Is this a bug within Jenkins or am I misunderstanding what the dir() directive is used for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally speaking, The `dir()` directive's purpose is to change your current working directory to another directory on the jenkins agent where the build itself is running.

In your case specifically there is a limitation from the docker plugin side as explained in the following [issue's comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33510?focusedCommentId=357623&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-357623):

`dir` with an absolute path is not supported inside a Docker container. Simply start your `sh` script with `cd`. Or avoid using the `withDockerContainer` step alogether - if it works perfectly for you out of the box, great, otherwise forget about it.

So your current workaround `sh 'cd /src'` - *if we considered it a workaround* - is the recommended way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is a bug. And reported the issue here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-46055
The core maintainers seemed to feel that there isn't actually a problem because there is a workaround. *(the one you described of `cd <dir> && <cmd>`)*

My opinion is that you're using `dir` correctly, it's just broken.